# Heroku hosted PostgreSQL and PLV8

Tags: postgresql, heroku, postgresql-9.1, plv8

Does anyone know if Heroku is supporting PLV8, yet?  I watched a video from RailsConf 2012 where a member of the Heroku team [talks here](http://lanyrd.com/2012/railsconf/srhxg/) about how to use it with hstore, but I got the feeling this was what they do for internal projects.  Google'ing "heroku postgresql plv8" doesn't really turn up much.  If someone from the Heroku team sees this, it would be great to post any general timelines when this might be supported.

Comment: I know this question got closed as "not constructive", and it sort of isn't.  But, I'm confused right now about what to ask related to Heroku (and where to ask it). The Heroku website has a link to Stackoverflow and says "Open a discussion with fellow Heroku users on Stack Overflow."  So, that's what I did and it got closed as "not constructive".  IMHO, there needs to be better and clearer guidelines here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not currently support PLV8, but hstore is fully supported on 9.1 databases and above. To begin using it you can do:

```
heroku pg:psql
create extension hstore;
```

We do not have an immediate timeline for PLV8, but do hope to be able to support it sometime in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't have any immediate "needed" for it, but am very interested in it and I think with the new JSON data type in the 9.2 that it will be a very powerful combination.  I hope that you can support it by the time you look at upgrading people to 9.2 (or offering 9.2).

Comment: PLV8 support was added in June 2013: https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2013/6/5/javascript_in_your_postgres/